# How can I align my elements in HTML?

Tags: html, css, web, alignment, containers

I am currently working on a practice example website as part of my Computer Science GCSE course. I am having real trouble with the navigation CSS. The website is very much in progress, so I know it's not great, but here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <title>The Cotswold Jeweller</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Assets/css/normalize.css" media="screen" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Assets/css/main.css" media="screen" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Assets/css/grid.css" media="screen" type="text/css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="head">

            <h1>The Cotswold Jeweller</h1>

        </div>

        <div class="nav_contain">

            <ul class="nav">

                <li><h2><a href="index.html">Home</a></h2></li>
                <li><h2><a href="#">Services</a></h2></li>
                <li><h2><a href="#">Location</a></h2></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="wrapper">

            <p>Welcome to the home of The Cotswold Jeweller on the web. Here at The Cotswold Jeweller we offer a unique and reliable service to create a friendly and local experience for our customers. We are very proud to also stock products from many different popular and large groups, such as Citizen, Butler and Peach and many more while we still maintain our local, reliable ethos.</p>

            <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=The+Cotswold+Jeweller,+Granville+Court,+Shipston-on-Stour&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=The+Cotswold+Jewe&amp;sll=52.8382,-2.327815&amp;sspn=8.08612,21.643066&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=52.062826,-1.623898&amp;spn=0.006295,0.006295&amp;t=m&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>

        </div>

        <div class="footer">

            <p>Copyright 2014 &copy; The Cotswold Jeweller</p>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
body {

    background-color: #FFFFFF;

}

.wrapper {

    width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;

}

.head {

    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 32px;

}

.nav li h2 a {

    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    width: 366px;
    float: left;

}

.nav {

    list-style: none;
    width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;

}

.nav_contain {

    border-top: 5px #990000 solid;
    border-bottom: 5px #990000 solid;

}
```

I would like to have the navigation bar between, the two borders of the navigation container, but they are not aligned properly. Please can you provide a solution below. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `overflow: auto` to the .nav container. This will prevent its height from collapsing because it only contains floated elements.

```
.nav {

    list-style: none;
    width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Alternatively, adding this to .nav_contain has a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
.nav li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and remove the h2 tags.

You may also have to reduce the size of the "a" tags to get them to stay in a line on screen. I'm on a 1280px monitor at the moment and I had to reduce their width to 300px.

Another alternative is to just remove the li tags completely. The links should still display side by side, and because your borders are outside of ".nav" then they should contain it.

If it doesn't work, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

generally try to avoid fixed values like

```
 width: 1100px; //(1)
```

you can replace it for example by

```
width: 90%;  //(2)
```

the `(1)` is destroying your site on other resolution than yours. Use `(2)` to avoid it.

try this code: 
http://paste.debian.net/69881/